# Hiding or displaying columns and rows inside a table (not sheet) in excel using VBA nad input values of a text-based drop down list

Tags: vba, excel

I'm programming a table to display rows based on numeric values in one cell and text values in another (a drop down list). I completed the code for the rows, but can't seem to get my head around the columns.

Edit: What I'm trying to do is display one or two of many columns depending on what input value I have in a dropdown. At the same time as the number of rows displayed are dependent on another cell. E.g. if I have three types of candy, one per column. And in the rows I display how many of said candies I eat per day. I want to display only one of the candies, for x days. How do I code this? The row-part I solved, the column - i need help.

This is my current code, how should I go about solving my predicament?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Time_horizon")) Is Nothing Then

TH_row_update

TH_column_update

End If

End Sub

Public Sub TH_row_update()

Dim cell As Range


    For Each cell In Range("Time_horizon_Year")
        If cell.Value >= ActiveSheet.Range("Time_Horizon") Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf cell.Value <= ActiveSheet.Range("Time_Horizon") Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
    Next cell


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Public Sub TH_column_update()

Dim cell As Range


    For Each cell In Range("comparator_range")
        If cell.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("Combination_comparators") Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf cell.Value <= ActiveSheet.Range("Combination_comparators") Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
    Next cell


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go trough colums and cells:

```
For Each col In Range("comparator_range").Columns
    Debug.Print "column " & col.Address
    For Each cel In col.Cells
      Debug.Print "  - cell " & cel.Address
    Next cel
Next col
```

So lets say your range is A1:C5
The first for each will run for each column that exists in this range mean A B C

The second for each trough every cell inside of the colum, means A1-A5, B1-B5, C1-C5

Hope this help you already, if you need more informations just tell it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure, I edited my original post with (what I think is) a better explanation of what I want to produce.

Comment: Sry I don´t understand what you want to achieve. Could you add an example like before and after input value.